# MediatR - Handling current user in query

Tags: c#, mediatr, asp.net-core-2.2

What is the best way to model the current user in a query?  I'm creating a razor page application.  I need to be able to attach the current user when I am executing queries and commands.  Is there a recommended approach for doing this?

Comment: probably you can create an **abstract class** with **userId property** for all events and commands, have `IHttpContextAccessor` in it and assign the **userId**. Your question doesn't have any sample code or context, so we couldn't help much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The below approach works well for me as I have the get the user into a service layer that my Razor projects depend on.

As per the guidance by David Fowler [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/1078), I created a `UserAccessor` class as follows:

```
public interface IUserAccessor { ClaimsPrincipal User { get; } }

public class UserAccessor : IUserAccessor
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

    public UserAccessor(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _accessor = accessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(accessor));
    }

    public ClaimsPrincipal User => _accessor.HttpContext.User;
}
```

which I register in my Razor project on startup by calling

```
services.AddTransient<IUserAccessor, UserAccessor>()
```

and then inject that into the MediatR handlers and my DbContext as well as some factories as required.

```
private readonly IUserAccessor _userAccessor;

public EventLogFactory(IUserAccessor userAccessor)
{
    _userAccessor = userAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userAccessor));
}
```

The `IHttpContextAccessor` referenced in `UserAccessor`  requires the *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions* nuget in projects that don't reference *Microsoft.AspNetCore.App* meta package and will also require that your Razor project implements `AddHttpContextAccessor()`on startup as well:

```
// Register IHttpContextAccessor for services to get access to the HttpContext.  
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Out of interest, could the `IUserAccessor` also be registered as `Scoped` instead of `Transient` considering it's the same user data for the lifetime of the request?

Comment: @Pure.Krome Yes

Comment: public interface IUserAccessor
 {
  ClaimsPrincipal User { get; }
 }

Comment: Is it not coupling the mediatr handler to HTTP protocol? What about sending the user as part of the handler request?